# Why does "hello\\s*world" not match "hello world"?

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

Why does this code throw a InputMismatchException ?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("hello world");
System.out.println(scanner.next("hello\\s*world"));
```

The same regex matches in http://regexpal.com/ (with \s instead of \\s)

Comment: http://regexpal.com/ tests javascript regular expressions, not java regular expressions. You can try using http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm for testing java regular expressions.

Comment: @Marcelo my favorite online Java regex tester: http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/

Comment: @Matt Thanks, I bookmarked it for the next time I need one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Scanner, as opposed to a Matcher, has built in tokenization of the string, the default delimiter is white space.  So your "hello world" is getting tokenized into "hello" "world" before the match runs.  It would be a match if you changed the delimiter before scanning to something not in the string, eg.:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("hello world");
scanner.useDelimiter(":");
System.out.println(scanner.next("hello\\s*world"));
```

but it seems like really for your case you should just be using a `Matcher`.

This is an example of using a Scanner "as intended":

```
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner("hello,world,goodnight,moon");
   scanner.useDelimiter(",");
   while (scanner.hasNext()) {
     System.out.println(scanner.next("\\w*"));
   }
```

output would be

```
hello
world
goodnight
moon
```

Comment: And what if the string is hello:world then?! You should not make assumptions about what is in your input :S

Comment: How is that relevant to illustrating for Navin why his code doesn't work?  I said "It would be a match if:"  not "It would be strictly correct code suitable for production use if:" The input is clearly assumed to be "hello world" ;)

Comment: You could have just set an empty delimiter instead of a :

Comment: A delimiter of "" would tokenize the string into "h" "e" "l" "l" "o" etc etc.  I suppose some arbitrary unprintable control character could be used, but ultimately if you're parsing with a scanner the input needs to be in some way constrained.

Answer (score 2):

The default delimiter of a scanner are whitespaces, so the scanner sees two elements *hello* and *world*. And *hello\s+world* is not matching hello therefore a NoSuchElement exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

These inputs work:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\java"  RegexTest hello\s+world "hello      world"
'hello      world' does match 'hello\s+world'
```

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length > 0) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(args[0]);

            for (int i = 1; i < args.length; ++i) {
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(args[i]);
                System.out.println("'" + args[i] + "' does " + (matcher.matches() ? "" : "not ") + "match '" + args[0]  +"'");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of the scanner takes an optional Pattern that is used to split the input sequence into tokens. By default, that's a whitespace pattern.

Scanner#next returns the next token, if it matches the given pattern. In other words, the pattern that you pass into #next may not contain whitespace by default.

You can invoke #useDelimiter to configure the scanner for your use case.

Answer (score -1):

A Scanner has a default delimiter of `\\s+`
If you want to match only `hello\\s*world`, just call `scanner.useDelimiter("hello\\s*world"))` and then just `scanner.next();`

Alternativeley, you can call `scanner.useDelimiter('any (escaped) char that would not occur in your text ')` and use `scanner.next("hello\\s*world"))`

As a side note, if you want it to have at least 1 space, you want to use a `+` instead of a `*`

Comment: This does not work.  delimiter of "" tokenizes into h e l l o ' ' w o r l d.

Comment: I've already edited that :) You need to use some character that is certainly not in your input. Be aware that some characters are special regex characters, and you would need to escape them in order to use them. A safe character I always use is #